# android- help needed with stopwatch and countdown timer

Tags: android, xml, gradle, android-studio

I have two timers on one activity. One is a countdown timer, the other is a stopwatch.

For the countdown timer, I want to modify my code to let user put in the amount of time for the countdown (in the format of hours or minutes, not seconds if possible) and also to make a reset button reset it. Currently my code only counts down from a set amount specified in the code.

Also if possible, I'm not sure so I'm asking - is it possible that when the count down timer hits "0", it vibrates the phone or does some kind of notification (would prefer vibrate.)

For the stopwatch, I just need to get my reset button working for that too.
Here is the code for the timers

```
 public class timers extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button btnStart, btnStop;
TextView textViewTime;
private TextView textTimer;
private Button startButton;
private Button pauseButton;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
long timeInMillies = 0L;
long timeSwap = 0L;
long finalTime = 0L;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timers);
    btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    textViewTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
    textViewTime.setText("00:03:00");
    final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(180000,1000);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.start();
        }
    });
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    });

    textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTimer);

    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart2);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);

        }

    });

    pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause2);
    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            timeSwap += timeInMillies;
            myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);

        }
    });

}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {
    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        textViewTime.setText("Completed.");
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        textViewTime.setText(hms);
    }
}
private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;

        int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
        textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":"
                + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

};

}
```

Code for layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Countdown Timer"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Stopwatch"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnStart2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#ffffb524"
    android:text="00:00:00" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTime"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewTime" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Stop"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTime"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewTime" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textTimer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFB524"
    android:text="00:00:00"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="152dp"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPause2"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:text="Pause"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textTimer"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/resetButton2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnStart2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStart2"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:text="Start"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnPause2"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textTimer"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textTimer" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Reset"
    android:id="@+id/resetButton2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnPause2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/setTime"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Reset"
    android:id="@+id/resetButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/setTime"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnStart" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to read the time input from the edittext once you put an @your_id on it and use findViewById(R.id.your_id) to get the view.  Then you can get its text using getText().

Reset button is similar to the start button you already have.  Just have it stop the timer and clear the edit text view.  If you use a field rather than a local variable it should be available to you inside the onclick method.

It is definitely possible to vibrate the phone on reaching zero. I would recommend a notification.  Read about the notification builder here.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html